# Create trigger statement inside an IF OBJECT_ID('TableName', 'U'): Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'. Expecting EXTERNAL

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-project

**EDIT: I later found out, it is not necessary to check for existence of tables, triggers etc, if using Visual Studio DB Projects.**

How can I create a trigger? The following gives me the error shown below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SomeSchema.tableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE SomeSchema.tableName ( ... 
  );
END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('SomeSchema.tableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  CREATE TRIGGER [SomeSchema].[triggername] 
    ON [SomeSchema].[tableName]  
  FOR UPDATE

  AS 
  BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN   

    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    UPDATE SomeSchema.tableName
       SET SomeColumn = GETUTCDATE(),
           OtherColumn      = HOST_NAME()
      FROM SomeSchema.SomeTable INNER JOIN INSERTED ON INSERTED.ID = 
           SomeSchema.SomeTable.Id
  END
END

Error:
SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.  Expecting EXTERNAL.
```

This is inside a visual studio database project. No this is not a clr trigger. It only gives me this error when the create trigger is inside an if statement.

Comment: is this a clr trigger,please post entire code

Comment: googling the error text showed at least 2 different reasons for this error. we need to see more code.

Comment: the problem is in one of the 4 dots between the begin end. For more detailed info you need to zoom in on the dots so we can read whats in them....

Comment: @GuidoG absolutely correct!

Comment: It cannot be contained inside an `IF` - [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799.aspx): "CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement in the batch ..."

Comment: I updated the question and in the meantime I also found the solution

Answer (score 1):

I have changed it to the following. This seems to work.

**The following check is not necessary if using DB projects.** I had no previous experience with db projects.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'triggername') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER triggername
go

CREATE TRIGGER triggername
  ON tablename
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN   

  SET NOCOUNT ON  

  UPDATE ...
END
```

Comment: Why are you checking for existence? The whole point of DB/SQL Projects is to compare your project to the database and bring them in sync. If the trigger doesn't exist, it will be created - you don't have to put extra code to check for that.  If it does exist, it will be altered to bring it in sync as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I had no experience with db projects before, and I learned only recently how it works.

Comment: This might be helpful - compilation of my experiences w/ SSDT - https://schottsql.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/all-ssdt-articles/  - not claiming to be an expert, but it could be helpful to get started.